# Use CAS protocol beside Asp identity cookie authentication in MVC web apps

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, cas

I have implemented a login system in my MVC web application using ASP Identity framework with owin. In addition to that, I need to integrate Central Authentication Service (CAS) into my login system as an external login mechanism.

All tutorials I found was only using CAS. Is there any way I could accomplish that?